# What's wrong with my fairy castle cactus?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, plant-recommendations, cactus

[image]

My cactus used to be really thick and dark green but now it's so much skinnier and starting to shrivel up. Some of the arms are turning a dusty kind of brown and they're all leaning away from the stem and drooping. I have checked for root rot which there is none the stem is perfectly healthy. I gave it more light but it's only getting worse I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your question, good illustration; if could include an overall illustration, overall height, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount & frequency, amount of sunlight per day, average daytime temperature, average night time temperature, size of container, soil type, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!